# JSON constructor to POST Javascript object via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have a custom eCommerce build for a client, which contains inputs that need to be sent to the server for hashing before the form can post.

The basic setup contains two select fields, one for the **flavor name** and another for its corresponding **quantity**. The user can *Add Additional Flavor*, which adds another set of flavor name and quantity selects.

Since the number of flavors (and their quantities) are dynamic, I need hash these values right before the form is posted via AJAX.

How do I create the constructor function for the JSON example below so that I can post the users values to my PHP script via `JSON.stringify()`

Basic JSON format I (think) I am after:

```
var flavorSelection {
  flavor1 : ["Bacon", "1"],
  flavor2 : ["Cheezy", "2"],
  flavor3 : ["Cheezy", "1"]
}
```

Sample select fields

```
<div>
<select name="flavors">
    <option name="bacon" value="bacon">Bacon</option>
    <option name="cheezy" value="cheezy">Cheezy</option>
</select>
<select name="qty">
    <option name="1" value="1">1</option>
    <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: If you show your actual AJAX code you might get more useful help

Comment: what hashing ? do you mean encoding json?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am formatting the data in PHP and inserting the response without much fuss - I am just having trouble properly constructing the JSON.

Comment: @meda, no I mean using a PHP HMAC hash function to encode the forms input values, which prevents tampering with them prior to sending them to the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your html markup to send arrays to your server

```
<div>
<select name="flavors[]">
    <option name="bacon" value="bacon">Bacon</option>
    <option name="cheezy" value="cheezy">Cheezy</option>
</select>
<select name="quantities[]">
    <option name="1" value="1">1</option>
    <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

not sure if it's the best way, but you will need to rely on the array indices to pair up your data.

you can easily loop and build your json the following way:

```
$flavors = $_POST['flavors'];
$quantities = $_POST['quantities'];

$json = array();

for($i = 1; $i <= count($flavors) $i++){
    $json[] = array('flavor'.$i => array( 
                         flavors[$i], quantities[$i]  
                    ));
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

That will give you the desired json, i don't know about hashing though.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do:

```
<div>
<select name="flavors[]">
    <option name="bacon" value="bacon">Bacon</option>
    <option name="cheezy" value="cheezy">Cheezy</option>
</select>
<select name="qty[]">
    <option name="1" value="1">1</option>
    <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

In PHP, when you use [] after form input names, the `$_POST["field_name"]` will receive an array.

then if you have 3 diferent flavors, your `$_POST["flavors"]` will receive an array with values "flavor one", "flavor two", "flavor three".

And your `$_POST["qty"]` will receive an array with the respective quantities of flavors, in the same order.

Then you use jQuery.serialize() to format your form data to submit using jQuery.ajax().

Comment: It's not old stuff, and it solves the problem!
With this format, he can just use jQuery.serialize() in the form and submit as data.